# Disable mat-step header button

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I would like to disable a final mat-step header button from working so the user can't navigate to the final page via clicking it. This is the relevant code:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Type</ng-template>
    <app-campaign-usage-mode [model]=model (stepNext)="stepper.next()"></app-campaign-usage-mode>
  </mat-step>

  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Details</ng-template>
    <app-campaign-details [model]=model (stepNext)="stepper.next()"></app-campaign-details>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Schedule</ng-template>
    <app-campaign-schedule [model]=model (stepNext)="stepper.next()"></app-campaign-schedule>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Creatives</ng-template>
    <app-campaign-creatives [model]=model (stepNext)="stepper.next()"></app-campaign-creatives>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="enabled">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Review</ng-template>
    <app-campaign-confirm [model]=model (stepEdited)="stepper.selectedIndex = $event" (stepNext)="stepper.next()"></app-campaign-confirm>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    <app-campaign-step9></app-campaign-step9>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

The last mat-step is the one I want to disable.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should declare `mat-horizontal-stepper` as **`linear`** as it makes sure that the validity of previous steps should be checked. Also, use **`completed`** in each `mat-step` to declare whether step is marked as completed.

Then, in each step write a click handler which will call `matStepClicked` function which will change each step's respective `completed` Boolean flag.

```
    <mat-horizontal-stepper linear #matHorizontalStepper>
        <mat-step [completed]="isFirstStepDone">            
           <ng-template matStepLabel>Type</ng-template>
          <app-campaign-usage-mode [model]=model (click)="matStepClicked(matHorizontalStepper, "FirstStep")"></app-campaign-usage-mode>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step [completed]="isSecondStepDone">
           <ng-template matStepLabel>Details</ng-template>
           <app-campaign-details [model]=model (click)="matStepClicked(matHorizontalStepper, "SecondStep")"></app-campaign-details>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step [completed]="isThirdStepDone">
           <ng-template matStepLabel>Details</ng-template>
           <app-campaign-details [model]=model (click)="matStepClicked(matHorizontalStepper, "ThirdStep")"></app-campaign-details>
        </mat-step>
    </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Then, in your `.ts` file write the click handler like this:

```
  matStepClicked(stepper: MatStepper, step: string) {
    switch(step) {
      case("FirstStep"):
        // perform some tasks
        this.isFirstStepDone = true;
        break;
      case("SecondStep"):
        // perform some tasks
        this.isSecondStepDone = true;
        break;
      case("ThirdStep"):
        // perform some tasks
        this.isThirdStepDone = true;
        break;
      default:
        // perform some other tasks
        break;
    }
  }
```

Also, don't forget to declare those completed flags(ie `isFirstStepDone`, `isSecondStepDone`) as `false` initially.

Please note, this click handler approach is more suitable if there's some logic to be performed in `.ts` file otherwise you can change those Boolean flag's value from within `html` like this: `(click)="isFirstStepDone = !isFirstStepDone"` or `(click)="isSecondStepDone= !isSecondStepDone"`

Answer (score 0):

As you use a formGroup for the steps you can block the final step with

`finalStep: MatStep
 finalStep.reset()`

This resets the step to its initial state. Note that this includes resetting form data
Provided that the formGroup of the previous step is also invalid